# call variable from another class

Tags: java, concurrency

```
 static int input;

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    public BusGenerator(Depot depot)
    {
        this.depot = depot;    
    }
    public int getinput()
    {
        return input;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Buses:" );
        input = scn.nextInt();
    }
```

I have a class called BusGenerator and from here i ask the user about the number of Bus and the system scans it and save it in the variable called "Input".

I have another class called Depot and i want to call the variable "Input" from the Class depot. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use BusGenerator.input;   in your Depot class

Comment: why not add a setter in your Depot class and pass it in to your depot instance?

Comment: @java fan..thank you...it worked!

Comment: @JohnKane yes that also a good way to achieve that.

Answer (score -1):

As the code is, you can simply use BusGenerator.input in the Depot class to refer to it (as pointed out in the comments).

However, since you've already defined a getter for this variable, it might be more consistent to make input private and refer to it with the public getter/setter methods.